# Beautiful Soup Headers with table data

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, imdb

I am scraping IMDB for the members of its cast (the IMDB API doesn't have comprehensive cast/credits data). The final product I want is a table with three columns that gets the data from all the tables in the webpage and sorts them like this:

```
Produced by | Gary Kurtz | producer 

Produced by | George Lucas | executive producer

Music by    | John Williams |
```

(using star wars as an example, http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/fullcredits?ref_=tt_cl_sm#cast)

The following code is almost there, but there is a ton of unnecessary whitespace, and the .parent function is surely being used wrong. What is the best way to find the value of the h4 above a table?

Here's the code.

```
 with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html5lib')
        soup.prettify()


        with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html5lib')
        soup.prettify()

        for child in soup.find_all('td',{'class':'name'}):
            print child.parent.text, child.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.parent.text.encode('utf-8')
```

I'm trying to get the values such as "Directed by" from these h4 headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow. It seems that you can find the `h4` and `table` at same time, as they appear as a pair in the html, so you can zip them to for loop over them. After that you just get and format the text. Change your code to:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(), 'html5lib')
for h4,table in zip(soup.find_all('h4'),soup.find_all('table')):
    header4 = " ".join(h4.text.strip().split())
    table_data = [" ".join(tr.text.strip().replace("\n", "").replace("...", "|").split())  for tr in table.find_all('tr')]
    print("%s | %s \n")%(header4,table_data)
```

This will print:

```
Directed by | [u'George Lucas'] 

Writing Credits | [u'George Lucas | (written by)'] 

Cast (in credits order) verified as complete | ['', u'Mark Hamill | Luke Skywalker', u'Harrison Ford | Han Solo', u'Carrie Fisher | Princess Leia Organa', u'Peter Cushing | Grand Moff Tarkin',...]

Produced by | [u'Gary Kurtz | producer', u'George Lucas | executive producer', u'Rick McCallum | producer (1997 special version)'] 

Music by | [u'John Williams'] 

...
```

Comment: Thank you for the warm welcome :D. This answer is perfect!

Answer (score 0):

this will avoid exhaustive use of the parent function

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#this will find all headers eg produced by
def get_header(url):
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
    headers = bsObj.find("div", {"id":"fullcredits_content"}).findAll("h4", {"class":"dataHeaderWithBorder"})
    return headers
#this will find all names eg gary kurtz
def get_table(url):
    bsObj = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
    table = bsObj.findAll("td", {"class":"name"})
    return table

url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0076759/fullcredits"
header= get_header(url)
table  = get_table(url)
#title  = get_title(url)
for h in header:
    for t in table:
        print(h.get_text())
        print(t.get_text())
        print("............")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I am getting a syntax error on the table = bsObj.findAll("td", {"class":"name"}).